# How to make a basic member system for a website

Tags: html, authentication, web, members

I want to make it so that people can log into an account that they've made using a signup form and I also want to make it so that when the account is created they it makes a profile page where they can edit their profile picture, banner, and bio.
I'm very new to well... everything so I need this explained in as much detail as possible.

Comment: Check out w3schools.com on how to use php/mysql together with html. They explain in detail.

Comment: http://daveismyname.blog/login-and-registration-system-with-php

Answer (score -1):

The concept is simple, consider the following

1.It can be done if you have implement a login system. First you should have page for the user profile, like changing name, picture, etc.... 
 2. Once they register you store the data in the db, with the user id (it can be auto increment column.
 3. In you navigation have link for user page, once use click it show page you created for user profile.
 4. When user login, store their user id in **session**, then based on their **user id** you can retrieve the information and show.
 5. The entire page input elements has to be inside a form tag, so if user edit something and click on the update button (or any name you wish) it will update the values in the db.

Basically in the register you will have the insert coding for the user table, and in the user profile page you will have the update coding.

Hope you get the idea!!

Comment: Like I said, I'm kind of a noob. That being, how would I...  
1. Make a signup form that creates the user's page  
2. Make a button on the navigation that links to the user's page  
3. Make a way to upload a picture  
4. Make a box where the picture displays  
5. make it so that when they hover over the picture it makes a button appear to edit the picture